# woocommerce variations and Quantity steps

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

woocommerce sample product have A,B,C variants
i want do that, when choosed "A" variant, Quantity steps goes  to 12,24,36... for "B", 6,12,18 ...for "C" 10, 20 ,30 ...
found an code for Quantity steps,  but i dont know how to modify it for that
thanks for help

```
// Simple products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
$args['input_value'] = 2; // Starting value
$args['max_value'] = 80; // Maximum value
$args['min_value'] = 2; // Minimum value
$args['step'] = 2; // Quantity steps
return $args;
}

// Variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' );
function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
$args['max_qty'] = 80; // Maximum value (variations)
$args['min_qty'] = 2; // Minimum value (variations)
return $args;
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////
I can pay for that 30$ who want supply my request

Comment: I think the solution to this would be very complicated. First you need to save meta for each variation defining the "step" and then you need to add that to the variation form's data attributes and *then* you'd need JavaScript to change the "step" on the front end depending on which variation is chosen.

Comment: can you code jscript for cost ?

Comment: Yes. You can contact me via the contact page at the website in my profile.

Comment: still needed someone doing my request

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I have the same

Answer (score 1):

before these code, i added custom field "_pro_pack_box" and "_pro_pcs_pack".
you can see this [article](http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/).

```
// Simple products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $pack_box = get_post_meta($product->post->ID, "_pro_pack_box", true);
    $pcs_pack = get_post_meta($product->post->ID, "_pro_pcs_pack", true);
    //if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
    //  $args['input_value']    = 2;    // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
    //}
    //$args['max_value']    = 80;   // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = $pcs_pack;    // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = $pcs_pack;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}

// Variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' );

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    //$args['max_qty'] = 80;        // Maximum value (variations)
    $args['min_qty'] = $pcs_pack;       // Minimum value (variations)
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's mores simple. For those who are interested in this issue still.
You just need to use JS. Your form has a $ (JQuery) object who includes WooVariationSwatches. Just change the value and step in this object.

Logic prototype:

```
A-variant->onclick {
  $('#yourform').data("WooVariationSwatches").element[0][4].step = 12;
}
```

Second step send your form on the button.
Ajax request will send correctly data.